# Deployment from multiple branches in Azure Devops yaml pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to deploy in my Dev Stage through Development and Feature branch in my YAML pipeline.
With Only Development branch option it is working fine i.e.

```
trigger:    
  branches:  
    include: 
    - release/*
    - development        
    - main
    - feature

stage: DEV
displayName: DEV
dependsOn: []
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development'))
```

But when I try to add multiple condition like below, then Job keeps getting skipped

```
condition: or(and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')), and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by updating YAML with below conditions

```
trigger:
 - development
 - release/*

pr: none

condition: or(and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')), and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/')))
```